# Overriding Java interfaces with new checked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, interface, overriding

Suppose in Java, I'm using a preexisting interface that is rather general

```
public interface Generator {
    public String generate();
}
```

and I have my own class

```
public class FromFileGenerator implements Generator {
    ...
    public String generate() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String output = //read from some file
        return file;
    }
}
```

The Java compiler yells at me because the implementation of generate() contains an exception not specified in the original signature (FileNotFoundException).  However, clearly the exception does not belong in the interface, but it also cannot be neglected in the implementing class.  How can this be resolved without simply failing silently?

Comment: Interfaces define contracts. Checked exceptions are part of the method signature, and thus the method contract. You must fulfill that *exact contract* to implement an interface.

Comment: @pst - Not exactly. An implementing method does not _have_ to be declared to throw all the checked exceptions of the method it is overriding; it just can't _add_ any new checked exceptions.

Comment: @TedHopp Ah. Memory-bank corrected. Thanks :) I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the implementation exception in an unchecked exception and throw that:

```
public class FromFileGenerator implements Generator {
    ...
    public String generate() {
        try {
            String output = //read from some file
            return file;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You cannot add a checked exception to the declaration of a method that hides, overrides, or implements another method. You will need to catch the exception within the method and do something else with it (such as return `null`, or throw an unchecked exception, possibly wrapping the checked exception).

From the [Java Language Specification, §8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> A method that overrides or hides another method, including methods that implement abstract methods defined in interfaces, may not be declared to throw more checked exceptions than the overridden or hidden method.

Answer (score 5):

Interface is a **contract** .

[image]

So you need to define that upfront.

So you can either do a try, catch within your method body or modify the contract.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to resolve it nicely: exception specifications are part of the interface, so if someone who programs to your `Generator` interface is not expecting to see `FileNotFoundException`, it shouldn't be coming to them when they use `FromFileGenerator`.

A common way to resolve it is by introducing a common exception, and wrapping `FileNotFoundException` in it:

```
public class GeneratorException extends Exception {
    public GeneratorException(Exception inner) {
        super(inner);
    }
}
public interface Generator {
    public String generate() throws GeneratorException;
}
public class FromFileGenerator implements Generator {
...
    public String generate() throws GeneratorException {
        try {
            String output = //read from some file
            return file;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            throw new GeneratorException(fnf);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not compile, for the same reason: the interface does not specify any exception, so the implementation can't throw a checked exception.

Comment: @Tom You're right, I created a common exception class, but forgot to add a `throw` declaration for it! Thanks, this is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

A common solution to this is to wrap the exception in an unchecked exception.  So your class might look something like:

```
public class FromFileGenerator implements Generator {
    ...
    public String generate() throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            String output = //read from some file
            return output
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Even better would be to change the interface to have its own checked exception.  Then you could convert from FileNotFoundException to that checked exception in the same way that you convert to the unchecked IllegalStateException above.