# Java Servlet return error 405 (Method Not Allowed) for POST request

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, post

My servet work fine for get requests but when I call POST (using jquery ajax $.post) I get error 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class init extends HttpServlet {
    public init() { }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("GET");
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, IllegalStateException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        ServletInputStream in = request.getInputStream();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("POST");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that doPost is not being called at all. Can you try running Postman or Advanced Rest client for Chrome to test and debug. Can you check you access log for tomcat and see what the request looks like.

Comment: @DavidC Log just show 405 and date. I can't test if doPost is called or not on the client.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure that you actually override the doPost Method?

The signature looks like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
           throws ServletException, java.io.IOException
```

but you specify it like this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
           throws ServletException, IOException, IllegalStateException
```

I am not sure whether this is allowed:
[Overriding Java interfaces with new checked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835633/overriding-java-interfaces-with-new-checked-exceptions)

Try the following steps:

1. Add the @Override Annotation
2. Remove the throws IllegalStateException (shouldn't be a problem as it is a runtime exception)

Comment: It work for both when I remove exception or when I added @Override. Thanks.

Comment: Detail simple and very powerful. I was doing the same error. Thanks!!

Answer (score 17):

This happened to me when my method call

"super.doGet(req, resp)" or "super.doPost(req, resp)" .

After i removed above super class calling from the doGet and doPost it worked fine.

Infact those super class calling codes were inserted by the Eclipse IDE template.

Comment: This is different issue

Comment: This helped me. Thanks